# Retrieve instances of objects on the server between GWT calls

Tags: java, servlets, gwt

Using GWT, I would like to save an instance of an object between client calls to a server. The instance of the object is on the server.

Like when using a pure servlet, I tried to associate it to the session but it seems that GWT opens a new session for each call.

Any hint would be useful...

Comment: Why do you think so that *GWT opens a new session for each call*? Have you validated it?

Comment: That's why I said it "seems", the Id we got from `this.getThreadLocalRequest().getSession()` was different.

Answer (score 0):

Use it in your [RemoteServiceServlet](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/server/rpc/RemoteServiceServlet.html) GWT remote service implementation classes to access the HTTP session.

```
HttpSession session = getThreadLocalRequest().getSession();
```

---

If it doesn't work then you can try with the **third party cache container**.

- [Infinispan](http://infinispan.org/about/)
- [EHCache](http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.4/user-guide/introduction#about-caches)